# Select all DOM elements until one of several DOM elements occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Using jQuery, I can use `$('h1').nextUntil('.class')` to select items between `h1` and `.class` DOM elements. But what if I want to select from `h1` to `.class` OR `.footer`, whichever comes first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) which is just separating the individual selectors with a comma.

```
 $('h1').nextUntil('.class, .footer')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('h1').nextUntil('.class, .footer').andSelf();
```

This will select from `h1` to `.class` OR `.footer` including `h1`.